# How to use bubblewrap to isolate app to single directory but access everything else?

Tags: linux

Let's say I have some software in `$HOME/myapp` that I would like to run in isolation, preventing it from accessing anything else in my home directory, but be able to access network, video, audio.

I tried to use bubblewrap to do this but cannot figure out how. I keep getting errors. Following [this tutorial](https://misile00.github.io/notes/Bubblewrap/), I arrived at:

```
#!/bin/sh

bwrap \
        --ro-bind /usr /usr \
        --ro-bind /etc /etc \
        --ro-bind /proc /proc \
        --ro-bind /dev /dev \
        --tmpfs /var \
        --tmpfs /tmp \
        --tmpfs /run --dir /run/user/$UID \
        --dev /dev \
        --proc /proc \
        --unshare-all --share-net \
        --bind $HOME/myapp $HOME \
        "$@"
```

I try this script but running bash so I can inspect the bound filesystem. But if I run `script.sh bash`, I get `bwrap: execvp bash: No such file or directory`. Ultimately, I want to run `$HOME/myapp/myexecutable` as `$HOME/myexecutable` inside the sandbox.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bwrap/bubblewrap, but does it make a difference if you run `script.sh /usr/bin/bash`? Just ruling out a $PATH issue.